# Message passing between popover and global page in safari extension without using globalPage.contentwindow

Tags: safari-extension

Is there a way to pass messages from the popover to global page using the dispatchMethod() instead of calling the global page's functions using safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow.

Currently i use a dynamically created iframe inside the web page to simulate a popover. This communicates with the global page using Safari's message passing. So i want to support this as well as the new popover in the later Safari versions.

Message passing between the popover and the global page will help me reuse the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a way for a popover to dispatch a message to the global page, or vice versa, using dispatchMessage. However, you could use the HTML5 standard window.postMessage to do the equivalent, although then you could not reuse your existing code without some modification.

To use postMessage from the popover, you would do something like this:

```
var gw = safari.extension.globalPage.contentWindow;
gw.postMessage("hello there", window.location.origin);
```

And to receive it in the global page:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (msg) {
    if (msg.origin == window.location.origin) {
        msg.source.postMessage("got your message", window.location.origin);
        doSomethingWithMessageData(msg.data);
    }
}, false);
```

This messaging protocol is similar enough to the extension-specific one that you could probably reuse most of your existing code, with just a thin abstraction layer added.

Comment: Would this create potential security related issues ? As a workaround my messaging flow looks like this currently: Popover -> Injected script -> Background page -> Injected script -> Popover

Comment: I suppose one can never overestimate the security risk when it comes to anything web-related, but I think it should be fairly secure. The value of `window.location.origin` will be something like `safari-extension://com.example.yourextension-0123456789`, which is unique to your extension. In the `postMessage` call, you are telling the browser to post the message only to windows that have that particular URL -- which will be only windows belonging to your extension. Then, in the message listener, you are doing nothing if the origin of the message is not the same URL.